# Yii and Payfast

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to integrate the Payfast (www.payfast.co.za) with the Yii php framework. Payments are working fine and I get the ITN callback but my database queries have absolutely no effect. I was wondering if it is perhaps some sort of restriction on the Yii famework etc. prohibiting a db query. Does anybody have any insight on this issue?

FYI, the request always redirects to payment success page but no database update. I have used the exact same logic with Codeigniter before with success, thus leading me to believe it might be a Yii issue.

The code responsible for doing the db query is as follows:

```
// If the transaction was valid
    if( strcmp( $result, 'VALID' ) == 0 )
    {
        // Process as required
          switch( $pfData['payment_status'] )
           {
               case 'COMPLETE':
                  // If complete, update your application, email the buyer and process the transaction as paid 
                  Order::model()->updateAll(array('paid'=>1),'reference="'.$pfData['m_payment_id'].'"');
                    break;
              case 'FAILED':                    
                    // There was an error, update your application and contact a member of PayFast's support team for further assistance
                   break;
              case 'PENDING':
                   // The transaction is pending, please contact a member of PayFast's support team for further assistance
                    break;
              default:
                    // If unknown status, do nothing (safest course of action)
              break;
          }

    }
```

The problem is that the switch doesn't seem to work? If you'd like to see the full code please see here:https://www.payfast.co.za/developers/php

Comment: Nope, we'd need more detail / code before we can hazard a guess

Comment: Hi acorncom. Noted and updated

Comment: are you sure that pfData is an array and correctly filled. Might not even get to the case statement at all. Log the data or dump it or something to confirm

Comment: I have copied this code exactly from a codeigniter application I have written earlier this year. The tricky thing about this code is that the ITN callback will not output any html etc. It writes to a log but that only tells me that the payment was successful, nothing about the actions taken after success message received.

Comment: Oh and the CI application worked perfectly. Unfortunately CI not an option in this case

Comment: I'd suggest you add some Yii logging to your success code.  You should then be able to see if you're having issues with your Order model or with Yii as a whole.  Have you tried saving your Order model with the same setup not in this code block?  It's possible you're having validation issues with your Order model ...